# Merge multiple objects into one and combine textures into one

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

Let's say i have a lot of objects , each one having their own texture , i want to join them all together ( ctrl+ J ) but i want to do the same for all of the different textures , how do we do that in blender?

I want all the props merged into 1 object and all different texture joined together as well.

Comment: Pretty new here so take everything I say with a grain of salt. From the sounds of it, you are looking for texture baking. I have tried it a few time and depending on how complicated your model is it can be a giant pain in the ass (for the inexperienced such as myself). This guy has a few easy to follow baking tutorials for beginners https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYvgFWEiNp8&pp=ygUfdGV4dHVyZSBiYWtpbmcgYmxlbmRlciBiZWdpbm5lcg%3D%3D. Hopefully this is what you're looking for! Good luck dude!

Comment: We don't usually do that for big numbers of objects, because then the texture files would have to be really huge in resolution.